# How to create own class App without intersecion with Kivy App?

Tags: python, kivy

I need to create a new class with name `App` and wrap default Kivy App method `run()`, but Kivy already has this name. What I tried to do:

```py
from kivy.app import App as KvApp


class SportApp(KvApp):
    def build(self):
        # here it builds

# my class
class App:
    def start_app(self):
        SportApp().run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App.start_app()
```

> App.start_app()
>
> TypeError: start_app() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: change `def start_app(self)` to `@staticmethod` `def start_app()` or change  `App.start_app()` to `App().start_app()`

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes, thanks

Comment: To use an instance method it is logical that you need an instance, isn't it logical for you?

Comment: @eyllanesc, yep, just understood it. It's mine inattention